# Open PHP pages in a jquery Lightbox type plugin

Tags: jquery, popup, lightbox

What I want is basically in the question title.

I have a website page, with a request a call back button. When thats clicked I want it to open a contact form, contact-us2.php in a lightbox type style plugin.

I have actually tried all the ones I can find, Colorbox, bumpbox, lightbox and many others but cant seem to get them to do what I want.

So:

```
<a href="contact-us2.php"  title="Request a call back" ><div id="call-back"></div></a>
```

when that link is clicked it will do what I described above.

Is there a plugin similar that will do this?

P.s. lightbox didnt work because im also using nivo slider which is jquery so that javascript from lightbox clashes with the jquery from the nivo slider. Hence request for a jquery plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try putting an `iframe` inside a lightbox plugin of your choosing. I like [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/).

Comment: I tried that fancy box. I had no clue how to use it. Put all the scripts in etc. and on my image link put rel="fancybox" but didnt do nothing. just opened image in a new page